# Контент с подвалом уходят вместе вниз

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Контент с подвалом уходят вниз и находятся на одном уровне. В чём может быть проблема? Сайт для понятия проблемы http://37.195.222.8/main.html

```css
 .footer{
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #22252d;
  color:white;
 }
 .content{
   min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
 }
```

```html
 <div class="footer">
  <h1> Летающий подвал </h1>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что у Вас в `ul.caption-style-2 li` заданы через `float:left`.

Задайте `footer` свойство `clear: both` и все будет корректно отображаться.